# How to generalize the (anti)commutation for spacelike separation to more than $2$ field operators?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, commutator, causality, anticommutator

Let $\phi_1$ and $\phi_2$ be quantum field operators of certain spin on $\mathbb{R}^4$. Then, the principle of locality dictates that if $x$ and $y$ are space-like separated, we have
\begin{equation}
\phi_1(x) \phi_2(y)=\phi_2(y) \phi_1(x) \text{ if at least one of } \phi_1, \phi_2 \text{ is Bosonic}
\end{equation}
or
\begin{equation}
\phi_1(x) \phi_2(y)=-\phi_2(y) \phi_1(x) \text{ if both of } \phi_1, \phi_2 \text{ are Fermionic}
\end{equation}

Now, I wonder how I can generalize this to more than two field operators. That is, for $n>2$, let $\phi_1, \cdots, \phi_n$ be quantum field operators. Then, exactly how should I state the local commutativity requirement for $\phi_1(x_1) \cdots \phi_n(x_n)$?

My guess is that I need to employ permutations $\sigma$ on $\{1, \cdots, n\}$ and consider the relation between
\begin{equation}
\phi_1(x_1) \cdots \phi_n(x_n)  
\end{equation}
and
\begin{equation}
\phi_{\sigma(1)}(x_{\sigma(1)}) \cdots \phi_{\sigma(n)}(x_{\sigma(n)})
\end{equation}
based on permutation of space-like separated Fermionic fields

However, the main difficulties I face are:

> How to make sense of space-like separation among multiple field operators?

> How to make sense of (or count the number of) interchanging Fermionic fields under the given permutation $\sigma$?

Could anyone please help me?

Comment: Isn't the obvious generalization that $\phi(x_1)\dots\phi(x_n)$ equals any permutation of it when all the $x_i$ are pairwise space-like separated, i.e. $x_i - x_j$ is spacelike for all $i,j$? What do you need this generalization *for*?

Comment: @ACuriousMind Well, I just want to see what happens in the presence of multiple field operators.

Comment: @ACuriousMind OK, if we suppose that all $x_i$'s are pairwise space-like separated, then when do we have the anticommutation relation? How do we make sense of interchanging Fermionic fields under the given permutation $\sigma$?

Comment: Odd permutation produces $-1$ for fermions

Comment: @nwolijin Of course. But what if permutation is over a mixture of fermions and bosons? What doed it mean by "odd" then?

Comment: Fermionic and bosonic fields commute. You have to take into account only permutations of fermionic fields

Comment: @nwolijin Well, how do you exactly define permutation of fermionic fields when the permutation mixes bosons and femions altogether?

Comment: @nwolijin That is, how do you "extract" that so-called "permutation of fermions" from the entire  permutation?

Comment: $\psi_1\phi\psi_2 = \psi_1 \psi_2 \phi = -\psi_2 \psi_1 \phi=-\phi \psi_2 \psi_1=\phi \psi_1 \psi_2$